# Breaking for loop when two same inputs in a row, Python

Tags: python, for-loop, input, comparison

I am making a code which calculates the average of credits the user inputs in Python. The loop should break, if the user inputs two zeros in a row and I have tried everything I can to make it so but I am having a hard time. Could someone help me? This is the code I have written so far. Sorry for bad English, I am a student from Finland :D

```
months = int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
list = []
loops = 1
for loops in range(1, months + 1):
   print("Enter the number of credits in month", loops, end="")
   credits = int(input(": "))
   list.append(credits)
```

*(now if credits are zeros two times a row)*

```
        print("You did have too many study breaks!")
        break
   loops += 1

average_credits = sum(list) / months
print("Your monthly credit point average is", average_credits, ".")
```

Comment: You should never call a variable the same name as a built-in name, like `list`. If you do that, in this case you wouldn't be able to call the `list()` function, for example.

Comment: why you increase the `loops` variable inside the `for` ? It's not affect the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Before converting the input string to int, check it if it is two leading zeroes.

```
months = int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
list = []
loops = 1

for loops in range(1, months + 1):
    print("Enter the number of credits in month", loops, end="")

    input_str = input(": ")

    if input_str == "00":
        print("You did have too many study breaks!")
        break
    credits = int(input_str)
    list.append(credits)
    loops += 1
```

Comment: If user add `0` separately this solution not work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question:

```
months = int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
count_zeros = 0
list = []
loops = 1
for loops in range(1, months + 1):
    while count_zeros < 1:
        print("Enter the number of credits in month", loops, end="")
        if credits == 0:
            count_zeros += 1
        credits = int(input(": "))
        list.append(credits)
        loops += 1
    else:
        print("You did have too many study breaks!")
        break
average_credits = sum(list) / months
print("Your monthly credit point average is", average_credits, ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the issue of two zeros in a row.

```
months = int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
list = []
loops = 1
for loops in range(1, months + 1):
    print("Enter the number of credits in month", loops, end="")
    credits = int(input(": "))

    # if the length of the list is not 0 (the array is not empty)
    # get the last element in the list and check if it is 0
    # if it the previous credit was 0, break the loop
    if len(list) != 0 and list[-1] == 0:
        print("You did have too many study breaks!")
        break
    list.append(credits)
    # loops += 1 - this line is not necessary, the loop will increment automatically in the range
    
average_credits = sum(list) / months
print("Your monthly credit point average is", average_credits, ".")
```